# AngularJS dropdownlist with treeview

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, treeview, custom-controls

I am new to angularjs, i want to use dropdownlist with treeview structure. i used both dropdownlist and treeview control separately but find difficulty in using together. can anyone have idea about how to use both together(dropdownlist+treeview)

Comment: i want this kind of control:- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ThirdParty/862784/TelerikTV2.PNG

Comment: Treeview and Grouped Select are quite different things (treeview typically has expand/collapse and multiple levels). The image you linked to is simply a select with grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple select control. I hope you are grouping values by some property. Lets say you have following data structure:

```
  $scope.data = [
      {
          id: 1,
          value: "Cat",
          type: "Animal"
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          value: "Dog",
          type: "Animal"
      },
      {
          id: 3,
          value: "Lion",
          type: "Animal"
      },
      {
          id: 4,
          value: "Parrot",
          type: "Bird"
      },
      {
          id: 5,
          value: "Sparrow",
          type: "Bird"
      },
  ];
```

You can group your data by "type" field and show a treeview dropdown as follows:

```
  <select ng-options="obj.value group by obj.type for obj in data track by $index"></select>
```

For more details you can look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Yashika i have one more dout... using your solution it will display like tree structure but it wont allow me to click main parent i.e (type)... basically my requirement is like if i select main parent then all its children also selected. e.g. in this case if i select Animal automatically all children of animal should be selected

Comment: I think for this, you have to manually add one record for parent category and write code to select all if Parent is selected. For example, in $scope.data, put first record as {id:0, value: "Animal", type: "Animal"} and keep a watch on what is selected. If selected is "Animal", select all - add all animal type objects in selectedData array

Comment: how to make a three level structure??